# Type III ANOVA vs Mixed Effects model - multiple comparisons of means and variances in R

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model

I am a biologist who wants to compare three cell lines to each other. I have three different cell lines that have been seeded into different wells in a plate. Due to factors out of my control I have different numbers of wells for each cell line. I have taken 40 images in different locations in each well and have gotten a mean intensity value for each image. Below shows an example of what my data looks like along with my attempted comparison.

I have two goals. (1) determine if the mean values of the intensities of the cell lines are different. (2) determine if the variance of the intensities of the cell lines are different.  I am interested in all pair-wise comparisons between all cell lines.

I have read many posts on here about mixed effects models vs repeated randomized block designs and how to do variance comparisons. However, the below things are still unclear to me:

1. I have one time point in which I am measuring some sub-sample of the total population of cells in each well (I never image the same cell twice). Which leads me toward thinking this is a randomized block design... which as far as I can tell is identical computationally to a repeated measures ANOVA. In R are these somehow different format-wise than what I have below?
2. If I'm using the randomized block design is there a more efficient/better way to do pair-wise post-hoc analysis than run three independent models (one for each cell line pair) and do a post-hoc (like Bonferroni) correction? Its fine here where I only have three lines, but in the future I'll have dozens and running a separate model for all two-way comparisons seems silly but do-able.
3. Because I don't have the same number of wells for each cell line. If I want to do comparisons should I really be using a linear mixed effect model because I am "missing" the wells to make the number of replicates the same?
4. If I want to compare the variances of intensity between my cell lines, there doesn't seem to be a way to do that for randomized block or linear mixed effect models(whichever ends up being correct from above). Below I create a column that is the residual from the median and do a type III ANOVA or LME on that.  But is that an acceptable way to assess differences in the variance of the intensity of the wells between cell lines?

```
# Creates a data frame with data  
mean_int <- c(runif(120, min = 40, max = 60), runif(160, min = 30, max = 50), runif(200, min = 70, max = 90))
cell_line <- rep(c("a","b","c"), times=c(120,160,200))
sub1 <- c(1:3)
sub2 <- c(1:4)
sub3 <- c(1:5)
rep(c(paste0("well",sub1),paste0("well",sub2),paste0("well",sub3)), each=40)
well <- paste(cell_line,well,sep="_")

df <- data.frame(cell_line,well,mean_int)

#******************************************************************************************************************
#Assess differences in means

# Performs a mixed (type III) ANOVA on data with one factor left out in each comparison. 
# I will then use a bonferonni correction to determine which cell lines are significantly different 
df1 <- df[df$cell_line != "a",]
df2 <- df[df$cell_line != "b",]
df3 <- df[df$cell_line != "c",]

aov_rb1 <- aov(mean_int ~ cell_line + Error(well), data=df1)
aov_rb2 <- aov(mean_int ~ cell_line + Error(well), data=df2)
aov_rb3 <- aov(mean_int ~ cell_line + Error(well), data=df3)
summary(aov_rb1)
summary(aov_rb2)
summary(aov_rb3)

# Performs a linear mixed effect model in which repeated measures from wells are controlled for within each cell line     
require(nlme)
require(multcomp)
lme1 <- lme(mean_int ~ cell_line, random = ~1|well/cell_line, 
                 data = df, method = "ML")

psthoc1 <- glht(lme1 , linfct = mcp(cell_line = "Tukey"))
sum1 <- summary(psthoc1)
sum1

#******************************************************************************************************************
# Assess differences in variances
# Creates a residual column where every value is median subtracted.a
unq_tech <- unique(df$well)    
i = unq_tech[1]
for(i in unq_tech){
    df_temp <- df[df$well == i,]
    df_temp$med_val <- median(df$mean_int)
    if(i == unq_tech[1]){ dft <- df_temp} else {
        dft <- rbind(dft,df_temp)
    }
}

dft$del_val <-abs(dft$mean_int-dft$med_val)
head(dft)

# Performs a 2-way ANOVA with Tukey's post-test on residuals
dft1 <- dft[dft$cell_line != "a",]
dft2 <- dft[dft$cell_line != "b",]
dft3 <- dft[dft$cell_line != "c",]

aov2_rb1 <- aov(del_val ~ cell_line + Error(well), data=dft1)
aov2_rb2 <- aov(del_val ~ cell_line + Error(well), data=dft2) 
aov2_rb3 <- aov(del_val ~ cell_line + Error(well), data=dft3) 
summary(aov2_rb1)
summary(aov2_rb2)
summary(aov2_rb3)

# Performs a linear mixed effect model in which repeated measures of residuals from wells are controlled for within each cell line     
require(nlme)
require(multcomp)
lme2 <- lme(del_val ~ cell_line, random = ~1|well/cell_line, 
            data = dft, method = "ML")

psthoc2 <- glht(lme2 , linfct = mcp(cell_line = "Tukey"))
sum2 <- summary(psthoc2)
sum2
```